# Considerations on publishing PhoneGap/Cordova application for Android

Tags: cordova

What are the important considerations when publishing an Android application which has been created by PhoneGap/Cordova?

- Remove `console.log()` from JavaScript files?
- Remove any other files from the project?
- Is there a *release* mode to be set?
- Any changes in *config.xml* or *AndroidManifest.xml*?
- Any place to add copy-right notes?
- How about application icons?
- Is publishing `\platforms\android\bin\*.apk` enough?
- Any other item?

Answer (score 0):

### You don't have to change anything

You have only one problem: you can't publish the apk file you find in the bin folder as it's signed with a debug key.

You need to export your application and create a key to sign the app with.

For more details you can follow the instructions on the Android Developer website

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahahahaha